# DisableAllInterrupts VS SuspendAllInterrupts (OSEK\VDX)

Tags: operating-system, embedded, interrupt, rtos, autosar

I would like to know the difference between `DisableAllInterrupts` and `SuspendAllInterrupts` in OSEK?

[image: DisableAllInterrupts description in OSEK doc]

[image: SuspendAllInterrupts description in OSEK doc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *disable/enable* interface is unsuitable for nesting.  The *suspend/resume* can be nested so that if a function suspends and resumes when the caller has already suspended, the interrupts will only be enabled on the outermost resume call.

The documentation also states that *suspend* saves the "recognition status".  It is not clear to me what that means; I have looked throughout the entire document and nowhere does it define that term clearly.  I assume that all interrupts that are recognised before are restored after the call.  That would (I guess) mean that if you enabled a new interrupt while suspended, the the resume might disable it.  Enabling a new interrupt in a *disabled* section on the other hand would persist after *enable*.  It is less than clear however IMO.

Nested suspend/resume will work as follows:

1. There will be a counter, that when *suspend* is called, if the counter is zero, then the interrupts are suspended, the recognition state is saved.  In any event the counter is incremented.
2. When *resume* is called, the counter is decremented, and if it becomes zero, then the recognition state is restored and interrupts enabled.

The effect of that is if you for example:

```
                     Nest-count    Interrupts
-----------------------------------------------
                         0         Enabled
suspend() ;              1         Disabled
    suspend() ;          2         Disabled
    resume() ;           1         Disabled
    suspend() ;          2         Disabled
        suspend() ;      3         Disabled
        resume() ;       2         Disabled
    resume() ;           1         Disabled
resume() ;               0         Enabled
```

If you are writing a critical section in a function that may be called from some other function you should use suspend/resume.  If you use disable/enable in the above scenario it would enable interrupts prematurely:

```
                     Interrupts
--------------------------------                     
                     Enabled
disable() ;          Disabled
    enable() ;       Enabled
    enable() ;       Enabled
    disable() ;      Disabled
        disable() ;  Disabled
        enable() ;   Enabled
    enable() ;       Enabled
enable() ;           Enabled
```

See in the enable/disable the *nesting* has no effect.  You should use nesting if you call functions from a critical section when such functions might also have critical sections within them - to ensure the outer critical section is not terminated prematurely.

Comment: what do you mean by nesting, nesting what exactly?

Comment: I though I'd explained that (albeit briefly) in the answer.  I have added a detailed explanation.  It is not really a matter of what _I mean_ - the term is used in the documentation, so what you are really asking is what does the documentation mean.  I am not familiar with OSEK specifically - I am reading the same documentation you are and drawing on knowledge and experience - the documentation is clearly not an RTOS tutorial and assumes you have that knowledge.  Perhaps your employer should spring for a training course?

Comment: I got it now, Thank you very much,